# Make a custom Apache handler (for multiple PHP versions)

Tags: htaccess

I've successfully installed PHP 5.2 and it runs as CGI.

(5.3 is my default running on mod, or as the phpinfo says "Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler")

Ultimately I want to put something like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52` in the .htaccess file of the directory I want to run it in. is that defined somewhere? (since in compiled php 5.2 myself)

*However*, this only really works in virtual hosts because I can't wrap my head around how to define a custom handler.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
ScriptAlias /php52-cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php52-cgi
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php52-cgi
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

How can I do something like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52` in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

**in /etc/apache/apache2.conf (or httpd.conf)**

```
ScriptAlias /php52-cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php52-cgi
Action application/x-httpd-php52 /php52-cgi
```

**in .htaccess (or virtualhost)**

```
<FilesMatch "\.php">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php52
</FilesMatch>
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

(don't seem to need the `AddHandler`, just the `FilesMatch`, can anyone explain why?)

I mostly followed [the instructions here](http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204)

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit an .htaccess file and add the following:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: that doesnt work. i even kept all the directives in the 000-default virtualhosts, not go either. did i mention that 5.3 is my default for everything running on mod.

Comment: No, you didn't. All you've mentioned is 5.2.

Comment: sorry, ive updated my question, i hope its more clear? (still working on my questions skills here) :) or? Yes, im running 5.3 as default and want to run certain directories in 5.2